# Управление коллекцией геообъектов с помощью меню в yandex-maps-api

Tags: html, jquery, css, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте! 
В Клубе Api Карт есть тема: "[Создание меню для отображения коллекций геообъектов](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/34779)" и пример с использованием "[Подключение существующего меню к геообъектам на карте](http://dimik.github.io/ymaps/examples/group-menu/menu03.html)". 
Я только учусь... 
Вопрос: 1.Как мне сделать ,чтобы меню было всегда свернутое, но чтобы объекты были на карте.
2. Меню со списком будет открываться только по клику.
3. При открытии меню карта остается фиксированной, а меню при открытии двигалось.
Спасибо за ранее, за Вашу помощь.

В примере, который я привел есть:

```js
// Обрабатываем клики на пунктах меню.
            $('.nav-header').on('click', function (e) {
                // Скрываем/отображаем пункты меню данной группы.
                $(this)
                    .nextUntil('.nav-header')
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .slideToggle('fast');

                // Скрываем/отображаем коллекцию на карте.
                groupToggle(this.id);
            });

            // Обрабатываем клики на пунктах меню эелементов группы.
            $('li:not(.nav-header)').on('click', function (e) {
                // Отменяем основное поведение (переход по ссылке)
                e.preventDefault();

                $(this)
                    .toggleClass('active')
                    .siblings('.active')
                    .removeClass('active');

                itemToggle(this.id);
            });
```

Не получается тут произвести манипуляции, чтобы "меню было всегда закрытое и при нажатии наоборот открывалось"

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

Для этого достаточно убрать добавление/удаление геообъектов c карты при клике по пунктам меню из примера песочницы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list :

```
if (submenu[0].style.display != 'none') {
                //myMap.geoObjects.remove(collection);
                submenu.hide();
            } else {
                //myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
                submenu.show();
            }
```

Вот тут показано как: https://jsfiddle.net/32krt5y2/

Comment: Добрый день. При удалении, как вы говорите, куска функции список постоянно раскрытый и не действует клик.

Comment: Как я уже спрашивал....надо чтобы "меню было всегда свернутое, но чтобы объекты были на карте."

Comment: Не так https://jsfiddle.net/34dtyavt/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение путем вставки `.hide()`

```js
// Обрабатываем клики на пунктах меню эелементов группы.
  $('li:not(.nav-header)').hide().on('click', function (e) {
// Отменяем основное поведение (переход по ссылке)
  e.preventDefault();
```

но дело все в том, что при загрузке страницы список все равно в начале видно, а потом он только закрывается. Если у кого есть предложения?